What is the law on one who’s trying to keep a Mitzvah but does so imperfectly
If someone for example is trying to keep Shabbat, but does it imperfectly in ignorance, is he or she liable?
My understanding is there must be a warning. I’ve heard if they were to take this person to court, the accusers might be asked if they also keep Shabbat.

You should rephrase our question: do you mean doing a Positive Mitzvah imperfectly or transgressing out of ignorance?


וְאִם־נֶ֙פֶשׁ֙ כִּ֣י תֶֽחֱטָ֔א וְעָֽשְׂתָ֗ה אַחַת֙ מִכׇּל־מִצְוֺ֣ת יְהֹוָ֔ה אֲשֶׁ֖ר לֹ֣א תֵעָשֶׂ֑ינָה וְלֹֽא־יָדַ֥ע וְאָשֵׁ֖ם וְנָשָׂ֥א עֲוֺנֽוֹ׃
And a person who, without knowing it, sins in regard to any of יהוה’s commandments about things not to be done, and then realizes guilt: Such a person shall be subject to punishment. [Leviticus 5:17]


Thank you, much appreciated.  But you should mention that it says it’s an unintentional sin which one had to bring sacrifice for in those days.

Unlike the Karaites or Samarites, we never cite the scripture for ruling Halachah, because Rabbis might have arrived at very different interpretations.

@AlBerko The frudge does that mean? Of course we cite scripture. Scripture is the entire basis of the Rabbis’ “interpretations”. The Rabbis themselves—meaning, in your usage, the תנאים and אמוראים—base every ruling on a careful evaluation of scripture, comparison with other parts of scripture, and application of direct linear reasoning. Such “Interpretation” is nothing more than a clarification of the text’s most basic, practical meaning.

@Qwertrl What I meant is that citing a verse is NOT enough, one should provide a ruling Halachah that was derived from it. Also they are "supported" by scripture, not "derived" - different rabbis arrive at very diverse conclusions from the same text. There's no way of deriving meat and dairy from לא תבשל or the Teffilin from על ידך.
